# How to add multiple column and store in different output in MYSQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have 4 column in which i wanna get two sum values for 2-2 column individually

I am trying this

```
   SELECT (SUM (`user1`) + SUM(`user2`)),(SUM (`customer1`) + SUM(`customer2`)) 
   AS (`totalUsers`,`totalCustomers`) FROM `collection`
```

it was working for

```
  SELECT SUM (`user1`) + SUM(`user2`) AS `totalUsers` FROM `collection`
```

I was giving result

```
 RowDataPacket { totalUsers: 3345 }
```

So I thought of doing that in similar fashion,but it is not working for multiple sum result.It is giving

> Unhandled rejection Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS `totalUsers` FROM `collection`' at line 1

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define [aliases](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-alias/) individually for an expression/column.

```
SELECT (SUM (`user1`) + SUM(`user2`)) AS `totalUsers`,
       (SUM (`customer1`) + SUM(`customer2`)) AS `totalCustomers`
FROM `collection`
```